# Retrieve last 3 values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, bids

I have an SSRS table with the last 12 months' balance details. I need to create column that calculates the difference between the last and (last but one) months' balance. Eg: (July balance - June balance). Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you Database is Sql Server 2012 or later you should use [Lag function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh231256.aspx). Something like this:

```
select Month, balance, lag(balance) over (order by Month) as PreviousBalance
  from table 
order by Month;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using 2008 version. Also, I already have a query on the dataset(to load the entire year's data) on which the table is built. I would prefer to use some function in the "expression" editor in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have used AdventureWorks/MDXStepByStep database for query below that joins current month and prior month.

```
SELECT  CurruentDate    =   a.[DateKey]
        ,LastMonthDate  =   b.DateKey
        ,CurrentValue   =   a.[FullDateAlternateKey]
        ,LastMonthValue =   b.[FullDateAlternateKey]
        ,[Difference]   =   a.[DateKey] - b.[DateKey]
  FROM  [dbo].[DimDate] a
        JOIN [dbo].[DimDate] b
        on DATEADD(month, 1, b.FullDateAlternateKey) = a.FullDateAlternateKey
```